# POST 405 Ajax (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I use GET, it works. I used this code before but it doesn't work here. What is the way to solve this? Is the problem due to my jQuery Version?

xammp LocalHost

[index.html]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    var nick = $('input[name="nick"]').val();
    var pin = $('input[name="pin"]').val();
    if (nick == "" && pin == "") {
      document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Lütfen boş alan bırakmayın.";
    } else {
      alert(nick); 
      alert(pin);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/kontrol.php',
        data: { nick },
        success: function(cevap) {
          $("#sonuc").html(cevap);
          document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "s boş alan bırakmayın.";
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

[Kontrol.php]

```
<?php 
  $json = $_POST['pin'];
  $json2 = $_POST['nick'];

  echo $json;
  echo $json2;
?>
```

Comment: `Is the problem due to Jquery Version?` No. The error is coming from your server.

Comment: As stated in your question, a 405 indicates that the method being used, in your case `POST` is not allowed on the server. Please provide more details in your question about your server setup, specifically routes you have setup, additional libraries you may be using, server software etc.

Comment: I tried on the server, it worked. The problem looks like localhost.